# Can I install (or remove) Ansible role from Galaxy using ansible-pull?

Tags: ansible

I'm working with Ansible using `ansible-pull` (runs on cron).

Can I install Ansible role from Ansible Galaxy without login in to all computers (just by adding a command to my Ansible playbook)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to download and install roles from Ansible Galaxy from the command line, in a hands-off manner, possibly repeatedly (via `cron`). If this is the case, here's how you can do it.

```sh
# download the roles
ansible-galaxy install --ignore-errors f500.elasticsearch groover.packerio
# run ansible-playbook to install the roles downloaded from Ansible Galaxy
ansible-playbook -i localhost, -c local <(echo -e '- hosts: localhost\n  roles:\n  - { role: f500.elasticsearch, elasticsearch_cluster_name: "my elasticsearch cluster" }\n  - { role: groover.packerio, packerio_version: 0.6.1 }\n')
```

**Explanation / FYI**:

- To download roles from Ansible Galaxy, use `ansible-galaxy`, not `ansible-pull`. For details, see [the manual](http://docs.ansible.com/galaxy.html#installing-roles). You can download multiple roles at once.
- If the role had been downloaded previously, repeated attempts at downloading using `ansible-galaxy install` will result in an error. If you wish to call this command repeatedly (e.g. from cron), use `--ignore-errors` (skip the role and move on to the next item) or `--force` (force overwrite) to work around this.
- When running `ansible-playbook`, we can avoid having to create an inventory file using `-i localhost,` (the comma at the end signals that we're providing a list, not a file).
- `-c local` (same as `--connection=local`) means that we won't be connecting remotely but will execute commands on the localhost.
- `<()` functionality is **process substitution**. The output of the command appears as a file, so we can feed a "virtual playbook file" into the `ansible-playbook` command without saving the playbook to the disk first (e.g., playbookname.yml).
- As shown, it's possible to embed role variables, such as `packerio_version: 0.6.1` and apply multiple roles in a single command.
- Note that **whitespace is significant** in playbooks (they are YAML files). Just as in Python code, be careful about indentation. It's easy to make typos in long lines with `echo -e` and `\n` (newlines).
- You can run updates of roles from Ansible Galaxy and `ansible-playbook` separately.

With a bit of magic, you don't have to create inventory files or playbooks (this can be useful sometimes). The solution to install Galaxy roles remotely via push is less hacky / cleaner but if you prefer to use `cron` and pulling then this can help.

Comment: I'm using ansible-pull on my computers to manage them. I wonder whether it is possible install new roles in the same way

Comment: Yes, you can install roles by pulling them from Ansible Galaxy with `ansible-galaxy` command and running `ansible-playbook` as described above. Have you tried these steps? I tested this on Debian Wheezy but it should work fine on other platforms as well.

Comment: I need describe "ansible-galaxy install" in a playbook.

Comment: To download roles from Ansible Galaxy, use the `ansible-galaxy` command. You can even do this in a playbook using the [command module](http://docs.ansible.com/command_module.html) if needed. To execute a role downloaded from Ansible Galaxy, just include `{ role: galaxyusername: galaxyrolename }` in your playbook.

Answer (score 0):

I usually add roles from galaxy as submodules in my own repository; that way I have control over when I update them, and ansible-pull will automatically fetch them - removing the need to run *ansible-galaxy*.

E.g.:

```
mkdir roles
git submodule add https://github.com/groover/ansible-role-packerio roles/groover.packerio
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can.

```
# install Ansible Galaxy requirements via the pull playbook itself
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - command: ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is a chicken and egg problem with that. Ansible won't run if it can't find the roles mentioned in the playbook. And ansible-pull will always run the local.yml playbook. So there is no way to bootstrap the process without cloning and calling ansible-galaxy separately.